# Python: sorting files with a blank line causes errors

Tags: python, csv

I have some csv files that have a timestamp in one column.  I've got some python code that sorts by date:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import time
import datetime
import operator
import io
import os


def sortTasksCSV():
   with open(os.environ['JURGEN']+'Jurgen/nextActions/nextActions.csv', 'rb') as
 f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    tasklist=sorted(reader,key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
    tasklist.sort(key=lambda item: datetime.datetime.strptime(item[3], '%Y-%
m-%d (%a) -  %H:%M:%S'))
    output=io.BytesIO()
    writer=csv.writer(output)
    return tasklist
```

When I give it a file that contains a blank line I get an (reasonably understandable) error on the 'itemgetter(3)' line.  Ideally I'd like the code to gracefully deal with blank lines - I could loop though the lines first and remove the blank ones - but that doesn't feel very elegant - is there a better way in python?

Comment: Add a `filter(None, reader)` before sorting?

Comment: That indeed turns out to be exactly what I wanted (I'd never heard of filter)... If you make it an answer I'll accept... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filter(filterfunction, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out empty lines (or any other kind of lines) without using a loop. If you omit the filter function, (i.e. use `None`) it will filter out everything that evaluates to `False` when interpreted as a boolean, for example your empty lines.

In Python2, `filter` will create a new list with the filtered elements from the iterable. In Python 3, the result is itself an iterable. If you want it to return an iterable in Python 2, use `itertools.ifilter`.

Minimum example:

```
lines = map(str.split, """a b 5
c d 2
e f 6

g h 1
i j 9""".splitlines())

import operator
print sorted(filter(None, lines), key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

Output:

```
[['g', 'h', '1'],
 ['c', 'd', '2'], 
 ['a', 'b', '5'], 
 ['e', 'f', '6'], 
 ['i', 'j', '9']]
```